# Filter rows where column value is in list in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column with a single value and column of lists of values:

```
        period  node    key_players
0       0       ZF1013  [ZF1128, ZF176, ZF434, ZF469, ZF659]
1       0       ZF1014  [ZF1128, ZF176, ZF434, ZF469, ZF659]
2       0       ZF1015  [ZF1128, ZF176, ZF434, ZF469, ZF659]
3       0       ZF1020  [ZF1128, ZF176, ZF434, ZF469, ZF659]
4       0       ZF1025  [ZF1128, ZF176, ZF434, ZF469, ZF659]
... ... ... ...
1565    4       ZF898   [ZF1336, ZF1346, ZF3, ZF434, ZF481]
1566    4       ZF945   [ZF1336, ZF1346, ZF3, ZF434, ZF481]
1567    4       ZF948   [ZF1336, ZF1346, ZF3, ZF434, ZF481]
1568    4       ZF97    [ZF1336, ZF1346, ZF3, ZF434, ZF481]
1569    4       ZFM264  [ZF1336, ZF1346, ZF3, ZF434, ZF481]
```

I would like to filter where 'node' is in 'key_players'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a version of the visible part of your df (for the future pls follow this: [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))

I modified a few rows to have some where node is included in `key_players`

```
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""
        period  node    key_players
0       0       ZF1013  ['ZF1128', 'ZF176', 'ZF434','ZF469','ZF659']
1       0       ZF1014  ['ZF1014', 'ZF176', 'ZF434','ZF469','ZF659']
2       0       ZF1015  ['ZF1128', 'ZF176', 'ZF434','ZF469','ZF659']
3       0       ZF1020  ['ZF1128', 'ZF176', 'ZF434','ZF469','ZF659']
4       0       ZF1025  ['ZF1128', 'ZF1025', 'ZF434','ZF469','ZF659']
1565    4       ZF898   ['ZF1336', 'ZF1346','ZF3', 'ZF434,' 'ZF481']
1566    4       ZF945   ['ZF1336', 'ZF1346','ZF3', 'ZF434,' 'ZF481']
1567    4       ZF948   ['ZF1336', 'ZF1346','ZF3', 'ZF434,' 'ZF481']
1568    4       ZF97    ['ZF1336', 'ZF1346','ZF3', 'ZF434,' 'ZF481']
1569    4       ZFM264  ['ZF1336', 'ZF1346','ZF3', 'ZF434,' 'ZF481']
"""), sep = '\s\s+')
df['key_players'] = df['key_players'].apply(eval)
```

### Solution 1

We unwrap the list in `key_players` via `explode` and keep those rows where we have a match with `node`

```
df2 = df.assign(kp = df['key_players']).explode('kp')
df2[df2['kp'] == df2['node']].drop(columns = 'kp')
```

this prints

```
      period  node    key_players
--  --------  ------  -----------------------------------------------
 1         0  ZF1014  ['ZF1014', 'ZF176', 'ZF434', 'ZF469', 'ZF659']
 4         0  ZF1025  ['ZF1128', 'ZF1025', 'ZF434', 'ZF469', 'ZF659']
```

### Solution 2

If you do not mind looping through rows (generally discouraged with pandas) you can do this

```
df[df.apply(lambda row: row['node'] in row['key_players'], axis=1)]
```

with the same output